# NaNs appearing with Multindex assignment in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a problem where I'm trying to build a multiarray slice by slice, however I keep getting NaNs as a result. Here is a minimal working example:

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['zero', 'one'], ['x', 'y']], codes=[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=midx, columns=['A','B'])    #empty array
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2))                   #the array I want my slice to equal

df.loc['one']     # good so far
df.loc['one']=df1 # ok .....
df.loc['one']     # all NaNs

####### Output ########
>>> df
        A  B
one  y  0  0
     x  0  0
zero y  0  0
     x  0  0
>>> df.loc['one']
   A  B
y  0  0
x  0  0
>>> df.loc['one']=df1
>>> df.loc['one']
    A   B
y NaN NaN
x NaN NaN
```

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning `df1` to `df.loc['one']`, Pandas attempts to align the index values... and they don't.  Use the `values` attribute of `df1` instead

```
df.loc['one'] = df1.values
```

---

Hmmm... Even if they did line up, it doesn't seem to work.  My suggestion does work for your example but something is still up.

Assume `df1` is defined as:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2), index=['x', 'y'], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

---

This will give more assurance that values are lining up properly but it kinda grosses me out...

```
df.loc['one'] = df1.reindex_like(df.loc['one']).values
```

---

Another hack that adds the requisite level to `df1`

```
df.update(pd.concat({'one': df1}))
```